# How to calculate the number distribution of data in IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have a data consist of time and flux (4117 rows x 2 columns) I want to calculate and plot the number distribution of brightness variation between all pairs of two consecutive data points same as the picture [distribution of brightness variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wZ4O.png)

This is the code I used in idl

```
nx=4117
t=fltarr(nx)
f=fltarr(nx)
df=fltarr(nx-1)
dt=fltarr(nx-1)
n=4116
dff=fltarr(n)
dc=fltarr(n-1)

data=read_table('data.dat')
;print,data(0,*) ;this is t (time)
;print,data(1,*) ;this is f (flux)

; Plot the light curve

window,0
plot,data(0,*)/data(0,0),data(1,*)/data(1,0),yrange=[0.93,1.1],ystyle=1 

; calculate the flux difference (dff)

for i=0,nx-2 do begin
df(i)=data(1,i+1)/data(1,0) - data(1,i)/data(1,0)
dt(i)=data(0,i+1)/data(0,0) - data(0,i)/data(0,0)
endfor

for i=0,n-1 do dff(i)=min(df)+i*(max(df)-min(df))/float(n-1.0)

print,dff

; calculate the number distribution (dc), I want the counter to reset to zero after every point and start to count again

for i=0,n-2 do begin
c=0.0
for j=0,nx-2 do begin
IF (df(j) < dff(i+1)) or (df(j) > dff(i)) THEN begin
c=c+1
dc(i)=c
endif
endfor

print, dc(i)
endfor

end
```

when I run the code all the value of dc is 4116 . I think the way I calculated dc is wrong. Any suggestion to do this in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is this line:

```
IF (df(j) < dff(i+1)) or (df(j) > dff(i)) THEN begin
```

In IDL, `a < b` is shorthand for "the lesser of a and b", and `a > b` is likewise "the greater of a and b". So right now, your IF statement is actually evaluated as:

```
IF (df(j) or dff(i+1), whichever is less) OR (df(j) or dff(i), whichever is more) THEN begin
```

and since non-zero floats evaluate as TRUE in IDL, it's ultimately this:

```
IF TRUE or TRUE THEN begin
```

Because the IF statement is always true, `c` is always incremented, and every value of `dc` ends up being 4116.

To fix this, you want to use the relational operators `LT` and `GT`, which return TRUE or FALSE. In other words, your code should read:

```
IF (df(j) LT dff(i+1)) or (df(j) GT dff(i)) THEN begin
```